# Changing layer symbol across multiple scales in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, visibility

I have some Cycling paths as line features, and I need to adjust the line visibility. When zoomed 1-1000 I need to see all lines. When zoomed 1000+ I need to see only red lines. Of course not only colors but attributes are various. So in that adjustments I can view exact path contours, but zoomed out 1000+ I only see the location.

Red lines are center lines of the blue lines.

I can't export to other layer, because I need to upload layer to a server, where is one layer accepted.

[image]

Comment: Are these lines separate features, or is it a symbol that displays the different coloured lines?  How do you determine which is a red line and which is a blue line?

Comment: Blue lines are maximum precision contours of path (3 meters width). They are seperate. Red lines are center (axis) line of the path. Different attributes - different colors as well.
Someone draw blue lines with AutoCAD. After that I have created red lines in the exact middle of blue lines.

One guy advised me to check information in Field Calculator. Some nice coding language would solve my quiz.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarification.

Answer (score 3):

To do this I would use two layers based on the same data but with different definition queries on each to distinguish the two sets of lines.

You can then have different scale ranges set for drawing each layer.